# В чем разница между HttpClient и WebClient?

Tags: c#, http

Да, я знаю, что эта тема мелькала много раз. Я знаю, что WebClient это обертка для более старого HttpWebRequest. Знаю, что HttpClient - это более новый API для работы с HTTP.

У меня возникла задача. Есть сервис. Он ждет задачи из очереди. Ему прилетает задача, содержащая методанные. Среди этих методанных есть URL, по которому лежит файл, который надо оценить по размеру (валидировать) и скачать. Я провел ресерч в и понял, что для задач по типу "скачать файл" почти всегда советуют именно WebClient. Вопрос в том, есть ли в рамках данной задачи (повторюсь, просто скачать файл, предварительно получив его размер) какие-либо преимущества у HttpClient перед WebClient? Если есть, то, пожалуйста, назовите, какие.

Comment: Вы документацию не читали, верно?

Comment: HttpClient поддерживает все современные стандарты. WebClient - не все. В зависимости от того, по какому протоколу работает сервис, WebClient может оказаться не способен работать с ним. А HttpClient гарантированно сможет.

Comment: _почти всегда советуют именно WebClient_ - ну, это по двум причинам: 1) он появился давным-давно, поэтому советов по его применению больше; 2) он содержит некоторые удобные методы наподобие DownloadFile, а у HttpClient такого метода нет.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `HttpClient` тоже может одной строчкой отдать хоть массив байт, хоть поток. Так что то что метода `DownloadFile` нет, совсем не значит, что теперь его придется написать с нуля на низком уровне. 1-2 строки кода его заменят легко.

Comment: @aepot - да, конечно. Но всё-таки две строки кода больше чем одна.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov чудовищный промах со стороны мелкомягких, ага. :)

Comment: Это две разные библиотеки, у которых разные авторы и разное подражание разным другим существующим библиотекам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Смысл всего вопроса в том, что когда вы выполняете операцию ввода-вывода, у вас 2 пути, либо блокировать намертво выполняющий операцию поток, либо не блокировать. Выбор по идее должен быть основан именно на этом, а не на том "как скачать файл" - ведь это не единственная задача перед вами в плане работы с сетью, верно?

Вот так это делается с помощью `HttpClient`.

```cs
private static readonly HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
```

Можно так

```cs
private async Task DownLoadFile()
{ 
    using var stream = await client.GetStreamAsync("https://url");
    using var fs = File.Create("file.txt");
    await stream.CopyToAsync(fs);
}
```

или если файл небольшой, то даже так

```cs
await File.WriteAllBytesAsync("file.txt", await client.GetBytesAsync("https://url"));
```

Как видите, если читать [документацию](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=netcore-3.1), можно много всякого найти. Ну и количество строк кода от того, что вы решились использовать `HttpClient` точно не увеличится, а вот возможностей станет больше.

Многим поначалу страшно работать с асинхронностью, но она на самом деле не простая для понимания, но поднапрячься и освоить - оно того точно стоит. Начните с этого: [Асинхронное программирование](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/async).

> В чем разница между HttpClient и WebClient?

Первый современный и асинхронный, второй - устаревший и синхронный.

*Про разницу в качестве реализации протокола, поддержке `HttpClient` HTTP/2 и прочих современных технологий я даже молчу. Ну и скорость работы у него также выше, особенно при множественных одновременных запросах к серверу.*

К тому же именно `HttpClient` рекомендован Microsoft для новой разработки, все остальные `HttpWebRequest`, `WebRequest`, `WebClient` [считаются устаревшими](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks).

> Мы не рекомендуем использовать `WebClient` класс для новой разработки. Вместо этого используйте `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` класс.

Другими словами, заданный вами вопрос - даже не спорный. Вы же не спрашиваете, какой вам феймворк использовать для нового проекта: 3, 4 или 5. Очевидно, вы возьмете посвежее. Вот и с клиентами этими то же самое.

Comment: `второй - устаревший и синхронный` ну это ж не совсем верно, у второго есть [асинхронные методы](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=net-5.0)

Comment: @tym32167 а кто их когда использует из новичков? Я просто опустил этот факт, но вы правы, да.

Comment: @tym32167 ага, основанные на устаревшем EAP вместо TAP

Comment: @PavelMayorov там и EAP и TAP есть, поглядите на список методов.

Comment: @tym32167 найдите хоть один, я не нашёл

Comment: @PavelMayorov [WebClient.DownloadStringTaskAsync Method](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient.downloadstringtaskasync?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: @tym32167 а понял, я не тот список методов смотрел

Comment: @PavelMayorov спасибо за ссылку про асинхронное программирование, но что в это такого особенного? Что это такое я прекрасно знаю, более того, реализация в шарпах не сказать, что идеальная и не вызывающая вопросов. Одной из ключевых проблем на мой взгляд является засилье слов async/await. В это плане наверное лучше присмотреться к языку Go или некоторым новым идеям в Java https://habr.com/ru/post/503412/

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak если хочется реально красивый и полностью многопоточный код писать безо всяких асинков - вам дорога в функциональное программирование, например Erlang. А Го во всяком случае в винде, до дотнета далеко, и за последних пару лет он не догоняет в развитии, а отстает. Что касается шарпа, именно async/await позволяет писать просто и лаконично в одном методе то, что раньше приходилось разворачивать в несколько классов. Блокировка потока вместо асинхронного ожидания - пустая трата ресурсов операционной системы, это неэффективно, как бы красиво при этом не выглядел код.

Comment: @PavelMayorov го далеко до дотнета в каком плане? Если в плане создания десктопа и всего того многообразия, которое в той или иной степени умеет дотнет, то да. Но го вроде как делался чисто для работы с сетью. А вот в плане многопоточности, что по Вашему мнению прям легко делать в шарпах, что невозможно в го?

Comment: @Aleksej_Shherbak вы мне уже второй "ответ" пишете, но я не могу понять где я писал те слова которые вы мне приписали

Answer (score -3):

Бегло просмотрев методы, я заметил один очень существенный недостаток "древнего" метода: отсутствие встроенного метода возврата в основной поток. Сплошные вопрос-ответы: IsBusy, Completed, Changed и так далее. Основной поток придётся крутить в цикле или использовать ещё более сложные методы. Морока.

В новом методе это делается просто. (downloadTask).Wait()!!! (Powershell):

```
# https://adamtheautomator.com/powershell-download-file/

[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net")
[void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Net.Http")
$source = 'https://speed.hetzner.de/100MB.bin' # Set the source and destination
$destination = "$env:TEMP\100MB.bin"

# Create the HTTP client download request
$httpClient = New-Object System.Net.Http.HttpClient
$response = $httpClient.GetAsync($source)
$response.Wait()

# Create a file stream to pointed to the output file destination
$outputFileStream = [System.IO.FileStream]::new($destination, [System.IO.FileMode]::Create, [System.IO.FileAccess]::Write)
# Stream the download to the destination file stream
$downloadTask = $response.Result.Content.CopyToAsync($outputFileStream)

# вставляй любой код, следующий Wait остановит поток и будет ждать результата или выдаст его сразу (если он получен) и продолжит выполнение кода дальше

$downloadTask.Wait() # Вот где вся закорючка!!!

# Close the file stream
$outputFileStream.Close()
```

То есть, если ваша задача - выполнил и забыл, выбирайте старый метод без всяких awaitов - они ему не нужны. (да и ждать его мы всё равно не собираемся)

Если нужны дальнейшие действия с результатом, то новый. (Скорее всего, так и будет, не проверял без выполненного Wait() не будут освобождены ресурсы, что в итоге, при многократном использовании метода, окажется плачевным)

Comment: Интересно. Кто меня минусует бессловесно за powershell возможно? Можно подумать я c# не знаю. Нет времени поднимать его. Набросал на PS. Та же самая фигня под framework в другой упаковке. Бери код и пиши, трансформируй под свою "базу"