Проблема C# с WebClient
private async void Download()
{
    string pathGames = @"C:\Games";
    string zipFile = @"C:\Games\OrangeRP.zip";
    if (!File.Exists(pathGames))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Games");
    }
    label1.Text = "Начало загрузки...";
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    using (WebClient wc = new WebClient())
    {
        wc.Encoding = Encoding.UTF8;
        wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri("http://yuryshalom.beget.tech/File/OrangeRP.zip"), zipFile);
        wc.DownloadProgressChanged += (s, e) =>
        {
            progressBar1.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
            label1.Text = $"Идет загрузка. Загружено: {Math.Round((decimal)e.BytesReceived / 1048576, 1)} МБ/{Math.Round((decimal)e.TotalBytesToReceive / 1048576, 1)} МБ";
        
        };
        wc.DownloadFileCompleted += (s, e) => 
        {
            if (e.Error != null)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(e.Error.ToString());

            }
            else if (e.Cancelled)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Отменено");
            }
            
        };

    }
}


Всем привет. Помогите плиз. Пытаюсь сделать обычный лаунчер, который скачивает файлы игры, но не чего не получается, загрузка идет, но в какой-то момент не докочавшись останавливается, и вылазит такая ошибка: 
Помогите пожалуйста, мучаюсь с загрузкой уже 3-ий день

Попробуй useragent проставить.

Не совсем понял, где поставить?

В заголовках запроса.

WebClient является устаревшим в C#, используйте HttpClient. Если хотите разобраться в текущей проблеме, то изучайте ошибку внимательней, научитесь пользоваться отладкой, поставьте точку остановки и посмотрите что там в e.Error такое. Сейчас у вас просто "Во время работы WebClient произошла ошибка" - сами думаю понимаете, что это не ошибка.

Я пытался понять httpClient, но не понял что отвечает за загрузку файлов?

Примеров того, как скачать файл при помощи HttpClient полно. Там достаточно получить Stream ответа и начать его копировать в Stream файла. В любом случае, изучайте ошибку.

Спаисбо завтра изучу

Странно сейчас нормально скачалось

Я изучил ссылку на файл. Там скорость ~100кб/с и постоянно падает, качать лично у меня будет ~20 дней. Периодически происходят обрывы (сервер перестает отвечать). Вот скорей всего в ошибке вам про разрыв и говорит. Поэтому, я посоветовал бы вам сменить сервер. Ну а если хотите этот, чтож, придумывайте механизмы докачивания (однажды я такой писал).

Раз https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1315858/373567, два https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1134235/373567
